# Type of equipment to measure exact amounts of liquid

Tags: equipment

I have to sample $\pu{10mL}$ of liquid hundreds of times a day at work.

We use a $\pu{10mL}$ syringe to do so, but it takes a lot of time as they often allow more than $\pu{10mL}$ to be drawn in (*i.e.* rather than a blind action, we have to check the measurement increments to make sure it’s exactly $\pu{10mL}$).

Is there a type of syringe of other piece of equipment designed to draw in exactly $\pu{10mL}$ (or other amounts) of liquid?

Comment: Well, duh! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipette

Comment: In particular [automated pipetting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_pipetting_system) could do it all for you.

Comment: What liquid are you sampling, what accuracy do you need, and what are you doing this for?  Also, what's your budget? The more details you can supply, the better able we will be to recommend an appropriate tool.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_displacement_pipette

Answer (score 2):

If you need to measure $\pu{10.0\pm0.1 mL}$ repititively, then you can use an any available Bottletop Dispensers. For example, check [this](https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/fisherbrand-autoclavable-bottletop-dispensers-6/p-4753023) and [this](https://www.grainger.com/product/46Z314?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI29ar46mJ5wIVg8DACh3CNgWNEAQYBSABEgKPyfD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMI29ar46mJ5wIVg8DACh3CNgWNEAQYBSABEgKPyfD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!264922887006!!!g!439776547137!) out (see image below):

[image: Bottle-top Dispensers]

If you are in a educational facility, Fisher would offer attractive discount (request a quote from fisher representative in your area. For example, I got $\pu{1.0-10.0 mL}$ dispensers for less than $100/each in that way (I bought 15 of them though). Still, it is a good price.

Comment: I don't know why, but I find these so satisfying to use!

Comment: Yep, they are very convenient. I use them in undergraduate organic chemistry labs so students do not waste solvents using grad cylinders any more. Save time as well. :-)

Comment: I only remember getting to use them once when I was an undergrad - it was used for CDCl3, to measure out ca. 0.5 ml of solvent to make up an NMR sample. I guess it only really makes sense if you have a repetitive task (and a chemical that's reasonably harmless, of course).

Comment: Still, we even use them to measure nitrating reagent (just for safety issue). However, it need to be flush with at least a $\pu{1 L}$ of water every once a while to keep it from degrading. Last longer enough to be useful.

Comment: This could be a great solution if the OP needs to repeatedly *dispense* 10 mL of liquid; but it's possible he instead needs to repeatedly *sample* 10 mL of liquid (e.g., for some sort of production line QC).  That's why I asked him to explain what he needs it for.

Comment: Mathew, is that really that accurate? I thought that was the accuracy of volumetric glassware (class B) 10.0±0.1 mL?

Comment: Manufacturers have claimed it. I found they are pretty consistent (more of precision). Yet, I never attempted to check the accuracy since it wasn't my concern.

Comment: And, OP is using a syringe. Accuracy of this is compatible with syringes and a way fast.